# Automapper not updating collection objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm trying to update an existing EF Core entity that contains a collection but it always creates new objects in the collection instead of updating them.
I'm using `Automapper.Collection` and `Automapper.Collection.EntityFrameworkCore`.

```
services.AddAutoMapper((serviceProvider, cfg) =>
{
    cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
    cfg.UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel<MyDbContext>(serviceProvider);
}, AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

public class EFClient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<EFFeature> { get; set; }
}

public class EFFeature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class DTOClient
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<EFFeature> { get; set; }
}

public class DTOFeature
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

CreateMap<EFClient, DTOClient>(MemberList.Destination)
    .ReverseMap();

CreateMap<EFFeature, DTOFeature>(MemberList.Destination)
    .EqualityComparison((efFeature, dtoFeature) => efFeature.Id == dtoFeature.Id);
    .ReverseMap();

public async UpdateClient1(dtoClient)
{
    var efClient = await MyDbContext.Clients
        .Include(c => c.Features)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == DTOClient.Id);
    
    // This updates the features list objects without creating new ones
    mapper.Map(dtoClient.Features, efClient.Features); 
}

public async UpdateClient2(dtoClient)
{
    var efClient = await MyDbContext.Clients
        .Include(c => c.Features)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == DTOClient.Id);

    // This updates the efClient object but then replaces the members of efClient.Features
    mapper.Map(dtoClient, efClient);
}

public async UpdateClient3(dtoClient)
{
    // This again updates the Client object but then replaces the members of the Features collection
    dbContext.Clients.Persist(mapper).InsertOrUpdateAsync(dtoClient);
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to tell Automapper to ignore the Features collection THIS TIME (not part of the config as I want it to map by default) so that they could be mapped separately.

Is there any other way to get Automapper to do this?

I'm using .Net7 / ASP.Net 7 / Entity Framework 7.

Comment: You should avoid the use of automapper

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Not particularly helpful comment; is there an alternative library or approach that you think is better?
Automapper is used throughout the application so using something else is probably difficult but may be possible if there's a good reason.

Comment: You need to use `EqualityComparison` to tell `Automapper.Collections` library how to compare items inside of collection. Please take a look at the official docs on github.

Comment: I didn't mean to make a helpful comment about automapper since there is no any real improvement using automapping, there is a lot of time and bugs for something that can be very simple to handle. Programming and a good thinked architecture is the best way to do a map IMO

Comment: @ExplodingKitten - You're right, I thought that `UseEntityFrameworkCoreModel` did that for me but I'd left an `EqualityComparison` in my code by accident and removing that did indeed break mapping the collection on its own so I've updated the code above. However, although mapping the collection on its own works, when the collection is part of the object being mapped, it doesn't work (creates new objects)

Answer (score 0):

I found a "workaround", but it's not nice so I'd still like a proper solution if anyone has one.
I updated my Automapper profile to ignore the collection and then added an `AfterMap` action to map the Features collection separately.

```
public class DtoClientProfile : Profile
{
    public DtoClientProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<DtoClient, EfClient>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(x => x.Features, opt => opt.Ignore())
            .AfterMap<MapFeatures>();
    }
}

public class MapFeatures : IMappingAction<DtoClient, EfClient>
{
    public void Process(DtoEdit source, EfClient destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        if (source.Features == null)
        {
            destination.Features = null;
        }
        else if (destination.Features == null)
        {
            // Mapping to a new object / one that doesn't already have a feature collection
            destination.Features = context.Mapper.Map<List<EfFeature>>(source.Features);
        }
        else
        {
            // Updating an existing feature collection
            context.Mapper.Map(source.Features, destination.Features);
        }
    }
}
```